# Add Deutsch language on swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization

I tried to add Deutsch Language on swiftui
I added two Localizable to the project and write "Welcome" for testing.

| English | Deutsch |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

after building the App I just saw the English version.
How Can I see in Deutsch??

---

By the way, I am new to SwiftUI so I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Try check out https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-test-localization-by-setting-a-debug-locale-and-double-length-pseudolanguage

Comment: Switch the system language?

Comment: I change the language in setting>general>language & region but nothing change in App

Comment: I think El Tomato is right, if you are using the Simulator I am relatively sure it is in english by default. To test if it works at all you can also just change the "Welcome" in english to "Welcome test". Besides I wouldn't use the normal english test as identifier in the strings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode:

1. Go to Product menu
2. Hold down option key and select Run...
3. Select Options tab and select German for the App Language
4. Run